# Enable/Disable Trigger in Sybase

Tags: sybase-asa

What's wrong with that query?

```
alter table TableName enable trigger 'TriggerName'
```

Error is

```
Line 1, column 30
Could not execute statement.
ASA Error -131: Syntax error nera 'enable' on line 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is from Sybase SQL Anywhere (ASA), but the syntax you're trying to use is not valid in ASA, it would be in Adaptive Server (ASE) though.  I [don't think there is an equivalent in ASA](http://sqlanywhere-forum.sybase.com/questions/389/how-to-temporary-disable-a-trigger-inside-a-procedure-and-enable-again).

Comment: My product is Sybase Adaptive Server Anywhere 8.0.3

Comment: Is it a case where triggers can't be disabled?

Comment: @Mauro - that's right.  If you review the SQLAnywhere Forum posting you'll see one approach is to change the code in the trigger to be conitionally executed based on a setting held in some table.  This allows you to control what the trigger does and simulate disable.  But it doesn't stop the trigger from firing.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the answer on the ASA forum that Martin pointed out http://sqlanywhere-forum.sap.com/questions/389/how-to-temporary-disable-a-trigger-inside-a-procedure-and-enable-again?page=1#13221 read it for details.

In summary you can use `SET OPTION FIRE_TRIGGERS = OFF;` or `SET TEMPORARY OPTION FIRE_TRIGGERS = OFF;`